# How To Check MAX value With a Pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example,

I have output like this :-

```
ID
---
AB1
AB2
AB3
AB4
BD6
```

If I use `MAX(ID)`, I will get `'BD6'` But I want to check `MAX` Value For Pattern `AB`

How can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply filter the Data with ID field and then use Max():

**EDIT**: If ID contains number with more than 1 digits:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM
    [Table] AS A
WHERE
    RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - 2) = (SELECT 
               MAX(Cast(RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - 2) AS Int)) FROM [Table] WHERE ID LIKE 'AB%')
    AND
    ID LIKE 'AB%'
```

Comment: if you have AB4 and AB111, then your query returns AB4. But it should be AB111.

Comment: your output is correct but Sub query is heavier than single query

Comment: when i exec your query i have "syntax incorrect key word as"

Comment: and if table have multiple values AB111 your take multiple rows ;) (except if id is uniq column)

Answer (score 1):

Try This. It will display all max ID for every String .

```
         select CONCAT(ID,id1) as ID   from
         (
         select left(id, patindex('%[^0-9]%', id) + 1) ID , max(cast(substring(id, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', id),len(id)) as numeric)) id1
         from #Table
         group by left(id, patindex('%[^0-9]%', id) + 1)
         )a
```

For Specific ID value like 'AB' put value into where clause .

```
         select CONCAT(ID,id1) as ID  from
         (
         select left(id, patindex('%[^0-9]%', id) + 1) ID , max(cast(substring(id, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', id),len(id)) as numeric)) id1
         from #Table
         group by left(id, patindex('%[^0-9]%', id) + 1)
         )a
         where ID like '%ab%'
```

> OutPut :

[image]

> outpur for AB111

[image]

Check also live [demo](http://rextester.com/NYSBC65689) here.

Comment: @Mr.PraloyDas  code upadted. it works alos for AB1111

Comment: But what is the purpose of adding '.' to id in your code (id+'.'). I am not able to understand that part. apart from that i am able to understand rest of the code.

Comment: @balaji You can also use only 'id' here. its works same

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT      'AB' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),MAX(CONVERT(INT, Nums.Numbers)))
FROM        (SELECT     Substring(ID, 3, 10) as Numbers
            FROM        #Tab tab
            WHERE       tab.ID LIKE 'AB%') as Nums
```

You can see this here => http://rextester.com/MAHKWE99983

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: if you have AB4 and AB111, then your query returns AB4. But it should be AB111.

Comment: @Mr.PraloyDas Yup, you are right. Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID VARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID)
VALUES('AB1'),('AB2'),('AB3'),('AB4'),('AB11'),('AB111'),('XY112')

DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR (10) = 'AB' 

SELECT  @Prefix + CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ID, (LEN(@Prefix) + 1),
(LEN(ID) - 2)) AS INT)) AS VARCHAR) AS ID FROM @TABLE WHERE ID LIKE
@Prefix +'%'
```

Comment: possibly the hardest way to achieve the result.

Comment: You should know which it correct before hit the "Not Useful Answer arrow". We are here to help other.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by this query.

```
create table temp
(
id varchar(10)
);
insert into temp values
('AB111'),
('AB1'),
('AB2'),
('AB3'),
('AB4'),
('BD6'),
('AB111')
;


declare @Pattern varchar(5)
set @Pattern='AB'
select distinct(Id) from temp where Id = @Pattern+convert(varchar(10),(
select MAX(Id) as Maximum from (
SELECT convert(integer,REPLACE( Id,@Pattern,'')) as Id FROM temp
where id like 'AB%'
)as test ))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with tmp as (
select 'AB1' id union all
select 'AB2' id union all
select 'AB3' id union all
select 'AB4' id union all
select 'AB111' id union all
select 'BD6' id
)
select top 1 *  from tmp f1
where  f1.ID LIKE 'AB%' and cast(SUBSTRING(f1.ID, 3, LEN(ID) -2) as integer) in 
 (
select max(cast(SUBSTRING(f2.ID, 3, LEN(ID) -2) as integer)) from tmp f2
WHERE f2.ID LIKE 'AB%' 
)
```

Comment: it will return only numbers without AB.

Comment: i have modified my query

Comment: not a noob downvote really, as I also commented what was wrong, now I removed it as you edited.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Tbl 
GROUP BY LEFT(col_name,2)
```

Comment: if you have AB4 and AB111, then your query returns AB4. But it should be AB111.